# MapStruct - Collection mapping with multiple sources

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm facing a weird issue with MapStruct when mapping collection with multiple source objects (It works with single source object).

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
    
    
    public MyVO mapEntityToVO(MyEntity entity); // WORKS

    public ArrayList<MyVO> mapEntityListToVOList(List<MyEntity> entities); // WORKS
            
    public MyVO mapEntityToVO(MyEntity entity, MySecondSource source); // WORKS
    
    public ArrayList<MyVO> mapEntityListToVOList(List<MyEntity> entities, MySecondSource source); // DOESN'T WORK (it produces empty list)

}
```

The implementation of the mapper outputs to this:

```
public class MyMapperImpl implements MyMapper {

    [...]

    @Override
    public ArrayList<MyVO> mapEntityListToVOList(List<MyEntity> entities) {
        if ( entities == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList<MyVO> list = new ArrayList<MyVO>( entity.size() );
        for ( MyEntity entity : entities ) {
            list.add( mapEntityToVO ( entity ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    [...]

    @Override
    public ArrayList<MyVO> mapEntityListToVOList(List<MyEntity> entities, MySecondSource source) {
       if ( entities == null && source == null) {
           return null;
       }

       ArrayList<MyVO> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyVO>();

       return arrayList;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the list is not populated with multiple sources. Is there a correct way to make it works?

Comment: Why not use the mapper as an abstract class instead and implement that method in a custom way? As far as I am aware mapstruct cannot know how to map 2 parameters onto one out of the box...

Comment: @mrkachariker it could be a workaround, but I want to know why it is not possible. I also tried to use `@Named("mapToVO")` on single entity method and `@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "mapToVO")` to the list one, but it doesn't work either. Is it a bug of the library?

Comment: Oh, I guess I was wrong, check this out: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mappings-with-several-source-parameters 
I guess you could specify your mapping entities like in the example: `    @Mapping(target = "description", source = "person.description")` It would be cool to provide a proper implementation of your classes

Answer (score 1):

The additional parameter should be annotated with `@Context` if meant to be passed to other mapping methods. The annotation was introduced in the 1.2 version, more info can be found in [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.4/api/org/mapstruct/Context.html).

---

Your method should be declared as:

```java
public ArrayList<MyVO> mapEntityListToVOList(List<MyEntity> entities, @Context MySecondSource source);
```

Additionally, a proxy method should be added to point MapStruct to the right single object mapping method.

```java
default MyVO mapContext(MyEntity entity, @Context MySecondSource source) {
    return mapEntityToVO(entity, source);
}
```

In case there is no proxy method, MapStruct would generate a new method for mapping a single object because the existing one doesn't contain a second parameter marked as `@Context`.